# How to represent the summation in matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have two vectors $a=[a_1, a_2,..a_n]$ and $b=[b_1,b_2,..b_n]$. A vector $c=[c_1...c_n]$ where 
$$c_i=\sum_{j=m}^l\alpha_j a_j+\sum_{j=k}^ h\beta_j b_j$$
In which, $i=1, \cdots, n; m,k \ge 1, m \le l \le n, k \le h \le n$ $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$ are coefficients in $\{0,1\}$. 
The above representing is to express a combination of random selecting elements in vector $a$ and $b$.

For example, $c_1=1.a_1+1.a_2+1.b_1; c_2=1.a_2; c_3=1.a_2+1.b_3, \cdots$

I want to represent above relationship of vector $c$ by using matrix. Could you suggest to me the matrix equation to represent it? Thank you

In my opinion, the vector $c$ maybe write as
$$c=
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
A_{1 \times 2n}
$$
where $A \in GF(2)$ is a matrix $1 \times 2n$

Comment: Your expression for $c_i$ is not well defined. What are $l,h$ supposed to be? Moreover, if you really want to define your $c_i$ like that, you obtain that all of them are exactly the same, which is not very fruitful

Comment: $l,h$ are up range which in $ m \le l \le n, k \le h \le n $

Comment: The representation $c_i$ is to express  is a combination of random elements in vector $a$ and $b$